# Check whole page for phone number and variations

Tags: php, phone-number

I want to variables

```
$phoneNumber
```

and

```
$siteContent
```

I now want to write a method and give those variables as parameters. The method should put the phone number from the $phoneNumber string in different variations and check the $siteContent if one of the variations is in there and if so, return yes.

As an example: The user types in following phone number: 02121 21413 or 02124/2144

The method should now put the phone number in the following formats

```
+49 30 1234567
+49 (30) 1234567
+49-30-1234567
```

and then check wether it is in the siteContent or not. I did the same once for the street address with replacing str. with strasse and other variations and did it like this.

```
$needles[0]   = strtolower( $value );
                $variants = array('straße','strasse');
                if($this->comparisonObject->compare($this->siteContents, $needles[0] , 'str.', 2, false) !== false)
                {
                    foreach ($variants as $variant) {
                        $needles[] = str_replace('str.', $variant, $needles[0]);
                    }
                }
                foreach ($needles as $needle) {
                    if($this->comparisonObject->compare($this->siteContents, $needle, 2, false) !== false)
                    {
                        return true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                        break;
                    }

                }
```

But I'm pretty unsure on how to achieve the same for phone numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: are you talking about picking up phone numbers from a public website or one of your own web pages?

Comment: I'm reading in a page with cURL and I'm getting the whole source code in the variable `$siteContents` - Now I just want to search this code for the phone number with the different variations that are possible and that I've written in my initial post.

Comment: I don't know what the difference would be when I have the number with strings saved in a string or by getting the whole page content in a string first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems the user is attempting to write code to perform web scrapping to collect personal information and I'm not sure the SO community would support this kind of work.